# Is there any sort of way to keep user updated on a variable value with tkinter module?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I've been trying to create a GUI calculator with python's tkinter module but I stumbled upon an issue. My goal is for the calculator screen to update with the inputted values from the user. However, when I ran the code below, I got no response when I pressed any of the buttons (except the mp3 one). I suspect that it is relating to the variable, "**expression**" and how it won't update every time a user presses a value. How can I fix this?

```py
from tkinter import *
from pygame import mixer

#TK window setup
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Calculator")
tk.geometry('600x600')
tk.configure(bg="pink")

# globally declare the expression variable
expression = ""


# Function to update expression
# in the text entry box
def press(num):
    # point out the global expression variable
    global expression

    # concatenation of string
    expression = expression + str(num)


    # update the expression by using set method
    equation.set(expression)


# Function to evaluate the final expression
def equalpress():
    # Try and except statement is used
    # for handling the errors like zero
    # division error etc.

    # Put that code inside the try block
    # which may generate the error
    try:

        global expression

        # eval function evaluate the expression
        # and str function convert the result
        # into string
        total = str(eval(expression))

        equation.set(total)

        # initialize the expression variable
        # by empty string
        expression = ""

    # if error is generate then handle
    # by the except block
    except:

        equation.set(" error ")
        expression = ""


# Function to clear the contents
# of text entry box
def clear():
    global expression
    expression = ""
    equation.set("")


def play_song():
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(r'C:\Users\jinge\Downloads\song.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()

equation = StringVar()
    







#Frame for the equation input
frame1 = Frame(tk, highlightbackground="blue", highlightthickness=1,width=600, height=80, bd= 0)
frame1.pack()
frame1.pack_propagate(False)

equation_area = Label(frame1, text=expression, font=("Times", 50)) #text needs to be edited to equation variable
equation_area.pack()

#frame for the buttons
buttons_frame = Frame(tk, highlightbackground="blue", highlightthickness=1, width=360, height=520, bd=0)
buttons_frame.pack(side="left")

#frame for the operation signs
operation_frame = Frame(tk, highlightbackground="blue", highlightthickness=1, width=240, height=520, bd=0)
operation_frame.pack(side="right")

#buttons 1-9
button1 = Button(buttons_frame, text="1", width=16, height = 8, bg="pink", command=lambda: press(1))
button2 = Button(buttons_frame, text="2", width=16, height = 8, bg="pink", command=lambda: press(2))
button3 = Button(buttons_frame, text="3", width=16, height = 8, bg="pink", command=lambda: press(3))
button4 = Button(buttons_frame, text="4", width=16, height = 8, bg="pink", command=lambda: press(4))
button5 = Button(buttons_frame, text="5", width=16, height = 8, bg="pink", command=lambda: press(5))
button6 = Button(buttons_frame, text="6", width=16, height = 8, bg="pink", command=lambda: press(6))
button7 = Button(buttons_frame, text="7", width=16, height = 8, bg="pink", command=lambda: press(7))
button8 = Button(buttons_frame, text="8", width=16, height = 8, bg="pink", command=lambda: press(8))
button9 = Button(buttons_frame, text="9", width=16, height = 8, bg="pink", command=lambda: press(9))
button0 = Button(buttons_frame, text="0", width=16, height = 8, bg="pink", command=lambda: press(0))
button_decimal = Button(buttons_frame, text=".", width=16, height = 8, bg="pink", command=lambda: press("."))

photo = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\jinge\Downloads\coolgif.png")
image_button = Button(buttons_frame, image=photo, width=120, height= 130, command=play_song)




#grid for buttons
button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
button3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="w")
button4.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
button5.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
button6.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w")
button7.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
button8.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w")
button9.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="w")
button0.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_decimal.grid(row=3, column=1)
image_button.grid(row=3, column=2)

#operation buttons
plus_button = Button(operation_frame, text="+", width=15, height=11, bg="cyan", command=lambda: press("+"))
minus_button = Button(operation_frame, text="-", width=15, height=11, bg="cyan", command=lambda: press("-"))
multiply_button = Button(operation_frame, text="X", width=15, height=11, bg="cyan", command=lambda: press("*"))
divide_button = Button(operation_frame, text="÷", width=15, height=11, bg="cyan", command=lambda: press("/"))
enter_button = Button(operation_frame, text="ENTER", width=15, height=11, bg="cyan", command=lambda: equalpress)
clear_button = Button(operation_frame, text="CLEAR", width=15, height=11, bg="cyan", command=lambda: clear)

#grid for operations
plus_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
minus_button.grid(row=0, column=1)
multiply_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
divide_button.grid(row=1, column=1)
enter_button.grid(row=2, column=0)
clear_button.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Comment: We can't use this code to reproduce this problem.

Comment: You did not include any code that calling `press()`, so how can we reproduce and identify the issue?

Comment: My apologies. Added

Comment: You've added too much. You need to provide a [mcve]. For example, do we really need close to 20 buttons to duplicate this or could we duplicate it with two or three? Do we really need coolgif.png to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not link the `StringVar` `equation` to label `equation_area`, so `equation_area` will not be updated.

Link `equation` to `equation_area` via `textvariable` option:

```py
equation_area = Label(frame1, textvariable=equation, font=("Times", 50))
```

Also the following lines should remove the use of `lambda`:

```
enter_button = Button(operation_frame, text="ENTER", width=15, height=11, bg="cyan", command=lambda: equalpress)
clear_button = Button(operation_frame, text="CLEAR", width=15, height=11, bg="cyan", command=lambda: clear)
```

Just use `command=equalpress` and `command=clear` instead.